# jQuery .click not working in if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

I have a connection to the Foursquare API in my application. The user can type in a box to start searching for venues, or they can click one of two venue links to fill the same select box with one of those two venues. I'm having trouble letting the user click one of either two venues in. Here is my code:

JS:

```
function venueFormatSelection(venue) {

  if ( venue.name && venue.location.address ) {
    // if a user starts typing into a box, venue.name and venue.address values will  pop up for them to select from. OR in the 'else' case, they can click one of either two links
  else {

    $("#bigdrop_set").click(function () {
      return $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_name')
    })

    $("#bigdrop_set_2").click(function () { 
      return $('#bigdrop_set_2').attr('venue_name_2')
    })

  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="which_venue" id="bigdrop_set" venue_name='foo' venue_data='FOO'><%= link_to(FOOOOO) %></span>

<span class="which_venue" id="bigdrop_set_2" venue_name_2='bar' venue_data_2='BAR'><%= link_to(BARRRR) %></span>
```

For some reason, the "click to populate" JS only works if just ONE of the 'return' lines is included without the .click function:

```
return $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_name')
```

What's wrong with the code inside my "else" statement? Thanks!

Comment: That code really doesn't make much sense; what do you expect that to do? Returning some value like that from an event handler doesn't mean much.

Comment: Why are you returning from an event handler?

Comment: The first spans id should be bigdrop_set   or am i wrong? and the first click function should be #bigdrop_set ?

Comment: Do you really have two `<span id="bigdrop_set_2">` in your code?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle..it will be easier to debug...

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(".bigdrop_set").click(function () {
  return $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_name')
  })
```

Should be:

```
$("#bigdrop_set").click(function () {
  return $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_name')
 })
```

As you are selecting an element with the ID bigdrop_set not an element with the class bigdrop_set. ID's should be unique, in your code you have duplicate bigdrop_set ID's which should be changed.

Also I would suggest binding the click elements on the `$(document).ready()` function, not in the `venueFormatSelection` function.

Returning the value from the click function doesn't really make much sense either.  Either manipulate the value directly in the function or put it in another function itself, not on the `click` event.

For example:

```
function alertVenue(venue) {
   alert(venue)
}

$("#bigdrop_set").click(function () {
   var venue = $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_name')
   alertVenue(venue);
})
```

Comment: i've replace my code with this alert function and added a section for #bigdrop_set_2. i have the alert successfully displaying the appropriate value when each link is clicked. however, i can't replace the alert with 'replace' to fill the select box with these venue values. thoughts on why return isn't working in this scenario? thanks!

Comment: @PaulOsetinsky to change the select box with the values you would have to do something like: $("#dropdownlist").val(venue);

Answer (score 0):

You have something like

```
$(".bigdrop_set").click(function () {
  return $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_name')
})
```

Did you really mean css class selector `.bigdrop_set` and then id selector `#bigdrop_set`.

Comment: no, i did mean #bigdrop_set. just edited. think the answer may be in Darren Davies' response. looking closer now

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix by using a global variable. Doubt it's the cleanest approach, but it's working for now:

```
$("#bigdrop_set").click(function () { 
  window.clickVenue = $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_name');
  $(".bigdrop").select2("val", $('#bigdrop_set').attr('venue_data'));
});

$("#bigdrop_set_2").click(function () { 
  window.clickVenue = $('#bigdrop_set_2').attr('venue_name_2');
  $(".bigdrop").select2("val", $('#bigdrop_set_2').attr('venue_data_2'));
});

function venueFormatSelection(venue) {

  if (venue.name && venue.location.address) {
    var imageSource = venue.categories[0].icon.prefix.slice(0, -1) + venue.categories[0].icon.suffix;
    return "<img src='" + imageSource + "' height='20' width='20' />" + "   " + venue.name + " (" + venue.location.address + ")";
  }
  else {
    return window.clickVenue;
  }
}
```